# Specefic if else statement in select query

Tags: mysql

I tried this select query with an IF statement but it didn't work,

Have you any solution

thank you

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `myProcedure`()
BEGIN
   set @sql=' Select IF(field1 = 1, \'Oui\', IF(field2 != 0 and field1 = 0,\'En 

    cours\', IF(field2 = 0 and field1 = 0,\'non\', \'non\'),\'non\'))  as Payed
    from myTable';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

error message :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),'non')) as Payed
```

Comment: You Can Use Case Statement instead of IF.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not fix your direct problem, but if you use `CASE` statements, the logic gets a bit easier to read:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field1 = 1 THEN 'Oui'
            WHEN field2 != 0 AND field1 = 0 THEN 'Encours'
            ELSE 'non'
       END AS Payed
FROM myTable
```

The ANSI compliant way to escape a single quote is by using two of them, e.g. `''`.  So your `@sql` variable would then look something like this:

```
SET @sql= 'SELECT CASE WHEN field1 = 1 THEN ''Oui''
        WHEN field2 != 0 AND field1 = 0 THEN ''Encours''
            ELSE ''non''
       END AS Payed
FROM myTable';
```

Comment: @Shadow Part of the OP issue is using `IF`, which requires many layers of nested parentheses.  I don't usually undelete a downvoted answer, but I did in this case because I think using `CASE` would solve two problems at once.

Comment: My downvote was due to the explanation that if() function cannot be used the way it was used in the OP. Since you corrected the answer, I withdraw the downvote.